# Run script on email received by virtual mailbox

Tags: postfix

I would like to run a script over email received by a virtual mailbox. I was hoping to do this with `.forward` in the virtual mailbox directory but it doesn't seem to be executing the script.

The idea is to extract attachments via munpack into another directory, but only when sent to that mailbox.

Mail Server is Postfix.

Comment: You need to specify a lot more: what mail server, how it is setup, etc..

Comment: sorry, I thought the tags would indicate that, `Postfix`. There is a lot of config, where should I start?

Comment: since your question is about virtual mailbox, pretty much anything related to that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run script on incoming email message to postfix](http://serverfault.com/questions/132576/run-script-on-incoming-email-message-to-postfix)

Comment: @mailq I think you are right. I missed that one.

Comment: @mailq the link you mention allows to trigger custom script after an email is received by the MTA, not neccesarily after the email is delivered to the mailbox, e.g., when the user doesn't exist in the local system, the content filter would still be executed, although no email would be delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option I have used before is to define your own delivery wrapper (I use maildrop for actual delivery - but this should work with any) then you can just do your stuff there. Something like this in `master.cf`:

```
maildrop unix -     n   n   -   -   pipe
  flags=Rhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop-wrapper 
  -d ${user}@${nexthop} -f ${sender} -A X-Delivery:maildrop
```

In maildrop-wrapper, do your stuff then just call the real maildrop:

```
#!/bin/bash
#do your stuff
#and/or:
exec /usr/bin/maildrop $@
```

You can run it before or after calling maildrop, **important note**: the script will receive the email via stdin, so you will have to buffer it if you intend to pass it to maildrop later (which the example above does not do). I would probably recommend using perl for this as there are more mail handling libraries there than in bare shell.

Edit: If you only want to do this for a single user then this is overkill, have a look at [maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/maildrop.html) - in particular the section about "external commands" via backticks. Define a maildroprc for this user with the rules required.

Comment: In order to use this approach and apply the filtering to only a specific mailbox I would need to write in a condition for the recipient... It seems messy for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that running for many years.
I added a redirection in the /etc/aliases file.

The mails that need processing by munpack are sent to robot@example.com.

So I wrote in the aliases file this line
robot : |"/home/robot/munpack-private.sh" user

so the mail gets processed by the munpack script and sent to the user mailbox

Comment: Interesting thread more detail:
https://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script